# How exactly does redux re-renders a react component?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Example I have a initial state like and set the initial state from a fetch post request from db:

```
const initialState = {
  posts: [],
};

export default function (state = initialState, action) {
  const { type, payload } = action;

  switch (type) {
    case SET_APP_INITIAL_STATE:
      return {
        posts: payload.posts,
      };
   
...
```

Note: here posts also contains array buffers (a bit heavy) which needs to be displayed on front end i.e. video's, images etc

And then in a component I fetch these using react redux and thunk reducers and try to display them, I do something like this:

```
const { posts: defaultPosts } = useSelector(state => state.myApp);


{defaultPosts && defaultPosts.length > 0 ? defaultPosts.map((singlePost, index) =>(
        <div key={index} className="post">
          <div className="postTop">
            <Avatar
              src={singlePost.profilePic}
              className="postTopAvatar"
            />
            <div className="postTopInfo">
              <h3>{singlePost.name}</h3>
            </div>
          </div>

        {singlePost.type === 'VIDEO' && singlePost.attachedMedia ? 
          <div className="postImage">
              <Video media={singlePost.attachedMedia} />
          </div>
        : null}

        {singlePost.type === 'PHOTO' && singlePost.attachedMedia ? 
          <div className="postImage">
              <Image media={singlePost.attachedMedia} />
          </div> 
        : null}
 .....
```

Here Video/Image component make use of ref's and set the src with the url below to display the video/image etc:

Note: singlePost.attachedMedia contains the arraybuffer and mime type info

```
    const image = new Blob([arraybuffer], {
      type: mimeType
    });
    const url = URL.createObjectURL(image);
```

Questions:

1. I do not try to deep clone the whole state and only modify it by doing something like this:

```
    case SET_APP_POST_LIKE:
      state.posts[payload.index].like = true;
      return {
        ...state
      };
```

Is this wrong? Reading on other blog posts make it seem like this is very bad practice but I am not sure if deep cloning it every time is the way to go?

2. Even when I press a like button my whole posts page gets rendered again? Is there a way to not render anything but only the like button. I have tested this by playing a video and when I press like it starts from start and also takes a second to load. (I think it re-renders)
3. Also should I change my state of having everything in posts to something like below. If yes then what will happen if I try to change the posts array? Will the whole state gets re-rendered again?

```
const initialState = {
  posts: [],
  media: [],
  comments: []
};
```

Please any help we will much appreciated, been stuck here for a while. Let me know if you want any clarifications. Thanks!

---

> EDIT 1:

---

Right now I have only **posts** array with all the media (array buffers of images, videos), comments and other stuff. Do you mean I should separate them into { posts, media, comments ...}?  I tried doing what you mentioned i.e.

```
const initialState = {
  posts: [],
  media: []
};
```

I refer to the media now as  const { media } = useSelector(state => state.posts);
And I update my state as

```
case SET_FB_POST_LIKE:
      state.posts[payload.index].like = true;
      return {
        ...state
      };
```

But still no luck!

Comment: Look at this way:

defaultPosts?.length > 0 && <div>something..</div>
it is more clean

Comment: Thanks, good catch!

Answer (score 0):

specify separated reducers, so you can use specific selectors, then combine your reducers in a global store like this:

```
const reducers = combineReducers({
  reducePosts,
  reduceMedia,
  reduceComments
});

const store = createStore(reducers, applyMiddleware(thunk));

export default store;
```

then your selectors should be single hooks like this:

```
const posts = useSelector(state => state.reducePosts.posts);
```

Comment: I made an edit to the original post, can you please refer to that!

Answer (score 0):

> I do not try to deep clone the whole state and only modify it by doing something like this:
>
> ```
> case SET_APP_POST_LIKE:
>  state.posts[payload.index].like = true;
>  return {
>    ...state
>  };
> ```
>
> Is this wrong? Reading on other blog posts make it seem like this is very bad practice but I am not sure if deep cloning it every time is the way to go?

Yes, this is a very bad practice, but deep cloning is a very bad practice too!

What you are doing is directly mutating the state by assigning the `like` property on an object in your array.  You would need to return a new state where all of the properties are copied except for `posts`.  `posts` would be a new array where all of the elements are the same objects except for the one that you are modifying, which is a new object.

This is not a deep clone because the only objects which are cloned are the ones that are actually changed.

That would look something like:

```
case SET_APP_POST_LIKE:
  return {
    ...state,
    posts: state.posts.map((post, i) =>
      i === payload.index
        ? {
            ...post,
            like: true
          }
        : post
    )
  };
```

Which is a real headache!

---

The modern way to write Redux is with [Redux Toolkit](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createSlice), which makes updating deeply nested properties like this extremely easy.  Instead of returning a new state, you just update a "draft" state by directly modifying the draft.

Your various branches of state become "slices" which each have their own reducer but get combined into one state.

```
// create the reducer and actions for the posts slice
const postsSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'posts',
  initialState: [],
  reducers: {
    setAppPostLike(state, action) {
      // just modify the property, don't return anything
      state[action.payload].like = true;
    }
  }
})

// action creator functions
export const {setAppPostLike} = postsSlice.actions;

// combine slice reducers into a store
export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    posts: postsSlice.reducer,
    media: // some reducer,
    comments: // some reducer,
  }
})
```

To like post #3, just call `dispatch(setAppPostLike(3))`.

---

> What will happen if I try to change the posts array? Will the whole state gets re-rendered again?

The `state` object is a new object, but the `media` and `comments` properties are the same.  Your components should be using `useSelector` to select just the parts of state that they need.  If the part that they selected was not changed then they won't re-render.

Instead of selecting the entire `myApp` property

```
const { posts: defaultPosts } = useSelector(state => state.myApp);
```

Just select the posts

```
const defaultPosts = useSelector(state => state.myApp.posts);
```

Or a specific post

```
const post = useSelector(state => state.myApp.posts[index]);
```